# Why does JavaScript sometimes creates the element i want and sometimes doesn't

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I'm using NodeJs and Socket.IO, and I have a form and at the moment fill an input and press TAB key I want to show every record from the database which match that input. And I have 2 forms. In first form it's working, but in the second form doesn't display anything. I've put some console.logs but for the second form it never reach the function. I've checked if I somehow wrote them wrong.

Can you please look over?

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addmother" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Add Mother</h5>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                  </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form action="/addmother" method="POST">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="lastname" id="lastname"  class="form-control" required onkeydown="onInputLastname(event)">
                                     
                        <span>or</span>
                        <hr>
                        <a href="/createaccft?userid=<%= target.userid %>&rel=mother" class="btn btn-info">Create an account</a>
                      </div>
                              
                                       
                                    
                                     <div class="lastnameresults" id="lastnameresults">
                                  
                                   
                                     </div>
                                     <hr>
                    <button class="btn btn-info"> Add</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

This is the working one.

And..

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addwh" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"> Add husband/wife </h5>
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                  </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form action="/addwh" method="POST">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="lastname" id="lastname"  class="form-control" required onkeydown="onInputLastname(event)">
                                     
                        <span>or</span>
                        <hr>
                        <a href="/createaccft?userid=<%= target.userid %>&rel=wife" class="btn btn-info">Create an account</a>
                      </div>
                                     <div class="lastnameresults" id="lastnameresults">       
                                     </div>
                                     <hr>
                    <button class="btn btn-info"> Add</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

This is the other
And this is the script

```
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>    
          <script>
    
    function onInputLastname (e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 13 || e.keyCode == 9) {
            
           var input = document.getElementById('lastname').value;
           console.log(input)
        var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3000");
      
if(socket !== undefined)
        {
          console.log('Connected to Live Server');
          
           socket.emit('input-lastname', {
              lastname:input
          })

         
          socket.on('output-lastnames', function(data) {
           var place = document.getElementById('lastnameresults');
          
          if(data.length > 0)
          {
              for(let i = 0 ;i < data.length;i++) {
                
                 place.style.display = 'grid';
                 var card = document.createElement('div');
                 card.className = 'profilecard';
                 var image = document.createElement('img');
                 image.className = 'cardimgstle';
                 image.src ="/"+data[i].profilePicture;
                 var hr = document.createElement('hr');
                 hr.className= 'hrstyle';

                 var span = document.createElement('span');
                 span.textContent = data[i].firstname +' ' + data[i].lastname;
                 span.className = 'spanstyle';
                 var hr1 = document.createElement('hr');
                 hr1.className= 'hrstyle';
                   var input = document.createElement('INPUT');
                   input.setAttribute("type","radio");
                   input.setAttribute("name","selecteduser");
                   input.setAttribute("value", data[i].userid);

                 card.appendChild(image);
                 card.appendChild(hr);
                 card.appendChild(span);
                 card.appendChild(hr1);
                 card.appendChild(input);
                 place.appendChild(card);
               
                 

                 
              }
          }
          })
          }
        }
        }
       
</script>
```

And this is the function in my app.js

```
 socket.on('input-lastname', function(data) {
           let lastname = data.lastname;
           console.log(lastname);
           NewUser.find({lastname:lastname}).then(r => {
              
               io.emit('output-lastnames', r);
           })
          
         
       })
```

I'd appreciate if you're making time for me, but I really don't know what's wrong.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Did you look for errors in the console? Did you add debugging statements to figure out what is wrong. Is it going into the ifs?

Comment: for the second form it never reach that function